# Display the URL after the link?

Tags: latex, hyperref

I use LaTeX with the hyperref package and I have things like:

```
hyperref is 
\href{http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/}{documented in detail}. 
It allows...
```

In the PDF output, it shows:

```
hyperref is documented in detail. It allows...
```

The link works but the URL is not displayed which is a big problem when printing the file. I do not find an option to change that [in the documentation](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/doc/manual.html).

Some of the hyperref files I work with are not generated by hand but by [dblatex](http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/) so changing every `\href{...}` is probably not an option.

For the hyperref side, see Will Robertson's solution. For dblatex, I wrote a customization script, by copying the XSL templates for `<ulink>` and similar elements and then producing a different LaTeX code. It is **no longer** necessary since the release of dblatex 0.2.10 which has the [necessary option](http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/html/manual/ulink.show.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest adding a switch in your preamble when generating "print-ready" versions of the output.

For example, (untested)

```
\newif\ifprint
\printtrue
\ifprint
  \let\oldhref\href
  \renewcommand\href[2]{%
    \oldhref{#1}{#2}%
    \footnote{\url{#1}}%
  }
\fi
```

Of course, you'll still need to generate two versions of the document, one for print and one for screen. But I'm not sure if you were expecting anything different `:)`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. 

The dblatex case is a bit more complicated because there is apparently no easy way to add this preamble. Working on it.